# STM32 RTC Default Interruption Doesn't Work, CubeMX Config

Tags: c, stm32, keil, cubemx

I'm starting with C & STM but..
I am using STM32L4476RG adn CubeMx and trying make a interruption by RTC clock e.g every day at 10 A.M (to blink LED or change some parameter's value at the beggining).

My code does not work, although it is generated by CubeMx, interrupt support is enabled, and the action at the interrupt is very easy so it can not be a problem.

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"


#include "stdlib.h"

RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;

static int mode_counter;
RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime;
RTC_DateTypeDef sDate;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim); //procedura przerwania od licznika
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin); //procedura przerwania od BlueButton
int Random_Number(int min, int max); //funkcja losujaca liczbe pseudolosowa z zakresu <min; max>
void HAT_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc); //RTC Alarm procedura


int main(void)
{


  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6); 

  while (1)
  {

    HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);  
    HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
    HAL_Delay(1000);

  }


}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 25;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC;
  PeriphClkInit.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSI;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);


  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}


static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef sAlarm;

  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  if(HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR0) != 0x32F2){
  sTime.Hours = 10;
  sTime.Minutes = 0;
  sTime.Seconds = 0;
  sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
  sDate.Date = 1;
  sDate.Year = 19;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc,RTC_BKP_DR0,0x32F2);
  }

  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours = 10;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds = 30;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  sAlarm.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  sAlarm.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_ALL;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDay = 1;
  sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}


static void MX_TIM6_Init(void)
{

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 2000;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 49999;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;


  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();


  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = BlueButton_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(BlueButton_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USART_TX_Pin|USART_RX_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);

}


void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
 if(htim->Instance == TIM6) 
    { 
        int _temp=Random_Number(1, htim6.Init.Period/2);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_10); //buzzer

        TIM6->ARR =(TIM6->ARR) +_temp;
    }
}
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if (GPIO_Pin == BlueButton_Pin)
        {
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BlueButton_GPIO_Port, BlueButton_Pin)==GPIO_PIN_SET)
            {
            mode_counter=mode_counter+1;
                switch(mode_counter)
                {
                    case 1: TIM6->PSC = htim6.Init.Prescaler*2; 
                        break;
                    case 2: TIM6->PSC = htim6.Init.Prescaler*4;
                        break;
                    default: TIM6->PSC = htim6.Init.Prescaler; 
                                     mode_counter=0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
}

int Random_Number (int min, int max)
{
  int tmp;
  if (max>=min)
    {
  max-= min;
    }
else
 {
   tmp= min - max;
   min= max;
   max= tmp;
 }
return max ? (rand() % max + min) : min;
}

void HAT_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc) // przerwanie od alarmu rtc
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    mode_counter=2;
}

void _Error_Handler(char * file, int line)
{

  while(1) 
  {
  }

}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{


}

#endif
```

Comment: Do you test every day at 10:00? Are your NVIC interrupts enabled in software? Please debug the code.

Comment: You may want to consider the pros and cons of HAL vs SPL.  CubeMX auto-generates a lot of code for you, but SPL has been around longer and is more stable.  Something worth reading: https://blog.domski.pl/spl-vs-hal-which-one-should-you-use/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I made typo in Interruption void.... Thx.